# Remove invalid characters coming from a Shrepoint list

Tags: regex, vba, sharepoint, character

I have linked a Sharepoint list by inserting a table in MS Excel. Some of the cell values within that table contain invalid characters which I see in the VBA Debugger or if I copy the cell value to Notepad++, visualized with a question mark. I have tried using regular expressions such as the one below but without success.
Any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Kind regards

```
Function SpecialReplace(ByVal Txt As String) As String
    Dim Rg As Object     
    Set Rg = CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
    With Rg
        .Pattern = "[0-9a-zA-Z]"
        .Global = True
        SpecialReplace = "A" & .Replace(Txt, "")
    End With
    Set Rg = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is rather simple:

```
.Pattern = "[^0-9a-zA-Z]"
```

GL with VBA struggle!

Comment: This also did remove valid characters, such as spaces or brackets. I guess at this point I just need to find the appropriate regular expression.

Comment: This is how I fixed it:

"[^\w\.@-\\ ()]"